Bound on spherical harmonic L2 norm from L_inf norm
The online notes here state the following as proposition 6.0.1.
If $f \in H_d$ then $$\sup_{x \in S^n} |f(x)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{dim H_d}{ \text{vol}(S^{n-1})}} |f|_{L^2},$$
where $H_d$ is the space of Harmonic polynomials of degree $d$ and $S^n$ is the sphere in dimension $n$.
My proof starts with $f(x)^2 = \langle f, Z_d(., x)\rangle^2$ for zonal harmonic $Z_d$. Then Cauchy-Schwarz says this is $$\leq \langle f,f\rangle \langle Z_d(.,x), Z_d(.,x)\rangle = |f|_{L^2}^2 \text{vol}(S^{n-1}) \sup_{y \in S^n}Z_d(y,x) \leq |f|_{L^2}^2 vol(S^{n-1}) dim H_d^2.$$ Taking square roots gives a weaker version of the inequality above. How can I tighten this to get the result claimed in the lecture notes?
